# Not able to release postgres client using npm-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Here is the code that I have tried.client.release() or client.end() is 
 giving me **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning** .I would want to release 
 the connection back to the pool or end it once data is inserted.

```
client.query(format(query, values), (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err, res);
            client.release();
          } else {
            console.log('POSTGRES DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY');
            //  client.end();
            client.release();
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the error you're getting.

Comment: What details do you need

Answer (score 0):

Your code mixes programmings styles. `client.release()` is what you use when you want to use the API with Promises, `client.query(query, callback)` is what you use when you want to use the callback API. It is not a good idea to mix the two.

If you want to use the callback style, then you should use the [callback style with `pool.connect`](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#-code-pool-connect-callback-err-error-client-pg-client-release-releasecallback-gt-void-gt-void-code-) too and call the `release` parameter that is passes to your callback:

```
pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
  // if err, report it.
  client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, result) => {
    // if err, report it.
    // do stuff, and then release the client
    release() // <--- call the 3rd argument passed to your callback
  })
})
```

If you want to use the Promise API, then you should rewrite your code like this:

```
  const client = await pool.connect();

  let res;
  try {
    res = await client.query("some query");
  }
  finally {
    await client.release();
  }

  // do something with res
```

The important thing is that this code handles the promise produced by `client.release()` so if it fails, you won't get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. Node will dump the error to the console and provide a stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

// This worked for me

```
const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/tpa';

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString,
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 10000
});

 pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
          if (err) {
            return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
          }
          client.query(format(query, values), (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err, res);
              release();
            } else {
              console.log('POSTGRES QUERY EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY');
              release();
            }
          });
```